# Spring data mongodb aggregate with LocalDateTime Can't find a codec for class java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

In a sample project I can successfully store this Bean:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Refrigerator {

    @Indexed
    private String deviceId;
    private String vendor;
    private LocalDateTime time;
    private Integer temperature;
    private Integer spoiledItems;

}
```

to this document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5acf302bd824ae010c55f3f0"),
    "deviceId": "myId",
    "time": ISODate("2018-04-07T10:08:40.921Z"),
    "temperature": 5,
    "_class": "com.github.paizo.monitorapi.model.Refrigerator"
}
```

but executing the following aggregation the operation fail:

```
@Override
public AverageTemperature averageTemperatureByDeviceIdAndDateRange(String deviceId, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to) {
    final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(
                    Criteria.where("deviceId")
                        .is(deviceId)
                        .andOperator(
                            Criteria.where("time").gte(from),
                            Criteria.where("time").lte(to)
                        )
            ),
            group("deviceId")
                    .avg("temperature").as("averageTemperature")
                    .addToSet("deviceId").as("deviceId"),
            project("deviceId", "averageTemperature")
    );

    AggregationResults<AverageTemperature> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Refrigerator.class), AverageTemperature.class);
    List<AverageTemperature> mappedResults = result.getMappedResults();
    return (mappedResults != null ? mappedResults.get(0) : null);
}
```

Same query without involving the dates succeed, this is the stacktrace:

```
DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Executing aggregation: { "aggregate" : "refrigerator", "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "deviceId" : "myId", "$and" : [ { "time" : { "$gte" : { "$java" : 2018-04-02T12:08:40.921 } } }, { "time" : { "$lte" : { "$java" : 2018-04-22T12:08:40.921 } } } ] } }, { "$group" : { "_id" : "$deviceId", "averageTemperature" : { "$avg" : "$temperature" }, "deviceId" : { "$addToSet" : "$deviceId" } } }, { "$project" : { "deviceId" : 1, "averageTemperature" : 1 } } ], "cursor" : { "batchSize" : 2147483647 } }

org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.LocalDateTime.

at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:184)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:182)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:182)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeIterable(DocumentCodec.java:207)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:180)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:182)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:182)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeIterable(DocumentCodec.java:207)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:180)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:141)
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:247)
at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:197)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:126)
at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:147)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:245)
at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:98)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:441)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:80)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:189)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:264)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:126)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:226)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:197)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:189)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:99)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:92)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandReadOperation.execute(CommandReadOperation.java:55)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:826)
at com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:166)
at com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:138)
at com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:133)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$4.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:440)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$4.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:437)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:437)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$BatchAggregationLoader.aggregateBatched(MongoTemplate.java:3137)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$BatchAggregationLoader.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:3113)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1937)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1841)
```

I found other questions related to issue with `LocalDateTime` and aggregate function however the converter should already be there since the  Jsr310Converters are included in [DATAMONGO-1102](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1102) Should I really have to fallback to standard `Date` type or I have to override the converter? if it is a limitation in the aggregation framework how can I workaround it?

I'm using Spring Boot `2.0.1.RELEASE`

Comment: Did you try with other classes from the `java.time` API, such as `Instant`?

Comment: Using the standard java `Date` it works and still convert from/to `ISODate("2018-04-07T10:08:40.921Z")` correctly; I haven't tried other JSR types to avoid falling on the same issue. My preference would be to use a Java 8 date/time

Comment: The mongodb java driver 3.7 (unstable) supports [JSR-310 Instant, LocalDate & LocalDateTime](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/whats-new/). Up to release 3.6 it relies on `java.util.Date` internally. I have encountered no issues since I switched to Java 8 and `java.time.Instant` for (de)serialization and aggregation, but also had troubles with `LocalDateTime`. So I'd suggest you either stick to `java.util.Date`, try with `java.time.Instant` or wait for mongodb 3.8 to use `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Having said that, I just run an aggregation that miserably failed because I matched an `Instant`... had to use `Date.from(Instant instant)` to make it work.